# Is it possible to know what is element was clicked inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a question with iframe.
For example I have html page which contains inside iframe.
Something like this:

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div style="text-align:center;">
  <iframe id="mysection" data="http://www.cnn.com" width="950" height="700"></iframe>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get any clicked element inside iframe. Is it possible or not?
Note: iframe src has not same domain

```js
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
      console.log("EVENT DUMMY ID");
      console.log(e.target);
      console.log("=====");
  });
```

Comment: You mean something like this ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I don't have access to src which added into iframe. I need not know what is element was clicked inside iframe

Comment: Hi Yury - your comment adds some useful context. It would be best if you edited your answer to include this extra information, so that anybody can read just the question and understand your complete problem.

Comment: Changed, thank you